# SELECT statement to remove empty columns from resultset with variable data

Tags: mysql, sql, select, dynamic-sql, sql-null

I've got a table that has been imported from a CSV as a midstep to gather data into other tables. All columns in this table may be empty but as long as one column has data, is a valid row. Because of this, there may be full rows with empty data, that are not valid to take into consideration.
Here's a (simplified) example of such a table:

```
/* Table Structure */
CREATE TABLE `imported_data` (
  `title` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

/* Table Data */
INSERT INTO imported_data (title, `description`, `language`, url, category) VALUES
('Le Titre', '', 'fra', '', '1'),
('', 'English Letters for Kids', '', 'https://anything.net', '2'),
('', '', '', '', ''),
('Master', 'The greatest master.', 'eng', 'http://www.master.com', '3'),
('', '', '', '', ''),
('', '', 'spa', '', '');


╔══════════╤══════════════════════════╤══════════╤═══════════════════════╤══════════╗
║ title    │ description              │ language │ url                   │ category ║
╠══════════╪══════════════════════════╪══════════╪═══════════════════════╪══════════╣
║          │                          │ fra      │                       │ 1        ║
╟──────────┼──────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────────┼──────────╢
║          │ English letters for Kids │          │ https://anything.net  │ 2        ║
╟──────────┼──────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────────┼──────────╢
║          │                          │          │                       │          ║
╟──────────┼──────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────────┼──────────╢
║          │ The greatest master.     │ eng      │ http://www.master.com │ 3        ║
╟──────────┼──────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────────┼──────────╢
║          │                          │          │                       │          ║
╟──────────┼──────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────────┼──────────╢
║          │                          │ spa      │                       │          ║
╚══════════╧══════════════════════════╧══════════╧═══════════════════════╧══════════╝
```

*NOTE: Please take into consideration the above table/data comes from an external source and is not modifiable, it has no primary key either. It is just imported as is in MySQL. I won't get `NULL` values as all columns are `VARCHAR`.*

I use the following SELECT statement to get this same table but without full empty rows this way:

```
SELECT title, `description`, `language`, url, category
FROM imported_data2 WHERE
title != ''  OR `description` != ''  OR `language` != ''  OR url != ''  OR category != '' 

╔═══════╤══════════════════════════╤══════════╤═══════════════════════╤══════════╗
║ title │ description              │ language │ url                   │ category ║
╠═══════╪══════════════════════════╪══════════╪═══════════════════════╪══════════╣
║       │                          │ fra      │                       │ 1        ║
╟───────┼──────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────────┼──────────╢
║       │ English letters for Kids │          │ https://anything.net  │ 2        ║
╟───────┼──────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────────┼──────────╢
║       │ The greatest master.     │ eng      │ http://www.master.com │ 3        ║
╟───────┼──────────────────────────┼──────────┼───────────────────────┼──────────╢
║       │                          │ spa      │                       │          ║
╚═══════╧══════════════════════════╧══════════╧═══════════════════════╧══════════╝
```

**What do I need to do to remove columns whose rows are all empty?** In this example, I need the table as above but without the empty column `title`.

As this data is dynamic, there may be times when another column or columns will be empty and I cannot know beforehand which one will be that way.

Comment: It's not possible to make the columns dynamic, only rows.

Comment: Unless you write dynamic SQL in a stored procedure.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display (if that's what this is) in application code

Comment: Generally handled in code after the fact, or you could create a temporary table with the results and drop columns on the temp table, then select * from the temp table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @GMB answer as a base, I added to the prepared statement a dynamic way to check if any of the verified fields are empty in the where clause, thus cutting out the full empty rows, like this:

```
set @sql = null;

select concat_ws(', ',
    case when count(nullif(title, ''))       > 0 then 'title'       end,
    case when count(nullif(description, '')) > 0 then 'description' end,
    case when count(nullif(language, ''))    > 0 then 'language'    end,
    case when count(nullif(url, ''))         > 0 then 'url'         end,
    case when count(nullif(category, ''))    > 0 then 'category'    end
) into @sql
from imported_data;

set @sql = concat('select ', @sql, ' from imported_data where',
                 (
                    SELECT INSERT( GROUP_CONCAT('OR `', `COLUMN_NAME`, '`  != \'\' ' SEPARATOR ' '), 1, 3, '')
                    FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
                    WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'mydb'
                        AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'imported_data'
                )
);  
prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the "empty" columns with:

```
select 
    count(title), 
    count(description),
    count(language),
    count(url),
    count(cagegory)
from imported_data
```

Columns that come back with a count of `0` contain only `null` values. You can then drop the related columns, if that's what you want.

> I won't get NULL values as all columns are VARCHAR.

A string column may sure contain `null` values. If you really mean empty string, not `null`, then use `nullif()`:

```
select 
    count(nullif(title, '')), 
    count(nullif(description, '')),
    count(nullif(language, '')),
    count(nullif(url, '')),
    count(nullif(category, ''))
from imported_data
```

If you want something entirely dynamic, then consider building use a prepared statement:

```
set @sql = null;

select concat_ws(', ',
    case when count(nullif(title, ''))       > 0 then 'title'       end,
    case when count(nullif(description, '')) > 0 then 'description' end,
    case when count(nullif(language, ''))    > 0 then 'language'    end,
    case when count(nullif(url, ''))         > 0 then 'url'         end,
    case when count(nullif(category, ''))    > 0 then 'category'    end
) into @sql
from imported_data;

set @sql = concat('select ', @sql, ' from imported_data');  
prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Comment: How would it leave the column out of the `SELECT` result if it's all empty?

Comment: Your second query is counting the empty values, not the non-empty values. So it won't return `0` when the column only contains empty values, it will contain the total number of rows.

Comment: @Barmar: the second query does return `0` for columns that have only empty strings (or `null`s). As for solving the problem itself, see my update, that provides a solution based on dynamic SQL.

Comment: Your prepared statement is surely the way to go. I was trying something similar too. The only problem with your solution as it is now is that the full empty rows remain (with no empty columns present). What is left to achieve that? Thanks!!

Comment: @GMB I've posted myself an answer based on yours with a possibility. If you think there is a better way, please edit your answer to take your idea into consideration. Thanks again!!