# Remove all empty columns dynamically from a table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a scenario very similar to [SELECT statement to remove empty columns from resultset with variable data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64342844/select-statement-to-remove-empty-columns-from-resultset-with-variable-data).

But in my case, I have a table with more than 300 columns!

I can write statically all the columns names in the prepared statements but I'm asking if there is a way to make this dynamic by looping through all the columns and checking if they only have null values then skip them.

Comment: Yiu can query information_schema.columns view to generate the checking sql statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need a `PROCEDURE`, a `CURSOR` and `PREPARED STATEMENT`

```
CREATE TABLE mytable2023 (id int, a varchar(10), b varchar(10), c varchar(10))
```

```
INSERT INTO mytable2023 VALUES (1,NULL,'B', NULL),(2,NULL,'B1', NULL)
```

> ```
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'mytable2023'; #TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database' AND
```

| COLUMN_NAME |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |
| id |

```
CREATE PROCEDURE delcolumn(
    tbname varchar(100)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE colname varchar(100) DEFAULT "";

    -- declare cursor for employee email
    DEClARE curcol 
        CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT COLUMN_NAME
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE  TABLE_NAME = tbname; #TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database' AND

    -- declare NOT FOUND handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

    OPEN curcol;

    getcol: LOOP
        FETCH curcol INTO colname;
        IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE getcol;
        END IF;
        -- build email list
         SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(`',colname,'`) INTO @count FROM `',tbname,'`;');
         PREPARE stmt2 FROM @sql;
         EXECUTE stmt2;
       IF @count = 0 THEN
         SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `',tbname,'` DROP COLUMN `',colname,'`');
         PREPARE stmt2 FROM @sql;
         EXECUTE stmt2;
       END IF;
    END LOOP getcol;
    CLOSE curcol;

END
```

```
CALL delcolumn('mytable2023')
```

```
SELECT * FROM mytable2023
```

| id | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | B1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QjRzfcsW)

Comment: Better would be if the table name was accepted as  input , so the procedure would be `CALL delcolumn(table_name)`  . I made a slight change on your fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/u-ujh1WD) +1

Comment: that wouldn't be enough the table name, is need more than once

Comment: upss my bad I missed that.

Comment: key is a reserved word, such words should be avoided, i adapted the procedire

Comment: You are my hero today! Thank you very much !!